# Heroky Deployment - Error: Missing required flag

Tags: heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an application by connecting my GitHub account to Heroku.

After hitting 'Deploy Branch' I get an 'Application error' when visiting my application url.

When running 'heroku logs --tail' in my terminal, here is my error:

»   Error: Missing required flag:

»     -a, --app APP  app to run command against

»   See more help with --help

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js run",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Name",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "balanced-match": "^1.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react-favicon": "0.0.14",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.4.2",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.43.0",
    "validator": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

Because I'm pushing my code directly from GitHub to a Heroku app, I don't really see why I should have to include the app name.

Comment: The missing flag error isn't related to your Application Error screen. That's just Heroku telling you it doesn't know which app's logs to show you. Run `heroku logs --tail --app yourappname`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right Chris, `heroku logs --tail --app yourappname` worked just fine. After looking in the error log, one of my node modules were imported with a misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set git remote to your application like this

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```